# If $e$ and $f$ are idempotent and $e(e+f)f=e+f$, then prove that $e=f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, idempotents

Let $R$ be an associative ring and let the idempotents $e$ and $f$ belongs to $R$. Then prove that

$$e(e+f)f=e+f \iff e=f$$

The *only if* part is very easy and I have proved what about the $(\implies)$ part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proving the $\implies$ part

\begin{eqnarray}
e(e+f)f &=& e+f \\
(e+ef)f &=& e+f \\
ef+ef &=& e+f \\
\end{eqnarray}

Now multiply above equation by $e$ (from left) and $f$ (from right) separately. We get

$$
ef+ef = e+ef
$$

and,

$$
ef+ef = ef+f
$$

Therefore,

$$
e+ef = ef + f
$$

which implies $e=f$ (since addition is commutative)